# Resetting Sql Server 2008 login (no access using management studio)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

I setup Sql Server 2008 a while ago on my machine.

I tried to connect with Management Studio and get the error login failed for user.

Its been such a long time since I set this up that I cannot remember the credentials.

How do I reset the credentials so this will work or do I have to uninstall and re-install?

Answer (score 1):

Login into SQL Server using Windows Authentication.

In Object Explorer, open Security folder, open Logins folder. Right Click on SA account and go to Properties.
**Change SA password, and confirm it. Click OK.**

restart the SQL Server and all its services and test new password by log into system using SA login and new password.

[Explanation Link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/12/29/sql-server-change-password-of-sa-login-using-management-studio/)